Is invariance under rescaling of the Lagrangian lost during quantization?
In classical mechanics, a field theory can be described by a lagrangian involving the field and its derivatives, $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}(\phi,\,\partial\phi,\,t).$ The equations of motion for the field can be obtained by means of the Euler-Lagrange equations,
$$
\partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}-\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi}=0.
$$
These equations of motion are invariant under a rescaling of the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}\rightarrow\mathcal{L}'=\lambda\mathcal{L}$, with $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, since
$$\partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}'}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}=\lambda\partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)},$$
$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}'}{\partial\phi}=\lambda\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi}.$$
Now, one can express this model in the Hamiltonian formulation by means of a Legendre transformation. One first identify the canonical momentum associated to each field (in my example, there is only one field $\phi$),
$$\Pi=\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_0\phi)},$$
and the Hamiltonian is
$$H=\Pi\partial_0\phi-\mathcal{L}.$$
The equations of motion are then obtained using the Hamilton-Jacobi set of equations,
$$\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial\Pi}\equiv\{\phi,\,H\}_{\text{PB}},$$
$$\frac{d\Pi}{dt}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial\phi}\equiv\{\Pi,\,H\}_{\text{PB}},$$
where $\{A,\,B\}_{\text{PB}}=\frac{\partial{A}}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial{B}}{\partial \Pi}-\frac{\partial{A}}{\partial \Pi}\frac{\partial{B}}{\partial \phi}$ is the Poisson braket.
Within this formalism, the rescaling $\mathcal{L}\rightarrow\mathcal{L}'=\lambda\mathcal{L}$ amounts to a shift in the conjugate momentum,
$$\Pi\rightarrow\Pi'=\lambda\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_0\phi)}=\lambda\Pi,$$
and a shift in the Hamiltonian,
$$H\rightarrow H'=\Pi'\phi-\mathcal{L}'=\lambda\left(\Pi\partial_0\phi-\mathcal{L}\right)=\lambda H.$$
One can check that, as a consequence of these modifications and of the definition of the Poisson bracket, the Hamilton-Jacobi equations are unchanged. So everything is consistent with the Lagrangian approach.
However, my question arises when one goes to the quantum theory. In this case, the fields $\phi$ and $\Pi$ are promoted to operators, and the Poisson bracket is replaced by the commutator,
$$\phi\rightarrow\hat{\phi},$$
$$\Pi\rightarrow\hat{\Pi},$$
$$\{\cdot,\,H\}_{\text{PB}}\rightarrow-\frac{i}{\hbar}[\hat{\cdot},\,\hat{H}].$$
My question is the following: now the equations of motion for $\hat{\phi}$ and $\hat{\Pi}$ are given by the Heisenberg equations
$$
\frac{d\hat\phi}{dt}=-\frac{i}{\hbar}\left[\hat{\phi},\,\hat{H}\right],
$$
$$
\frac{d\hat\Pi}{dt}=-\frac{i}{\hbar}\left[\hat{\Pi},\,\hat{H}\right].
$$
However, unlike what happened in the classical theory due to the definition of the Poisson bracket, now the equations of motion are not invariant under the transformation $\mathcal{L}\rightarrow\mathcal{L}'=\lambda\mathcal{L}$, which results in
$$
\frac{d\hat\phi}{dt}=-\frac{i}{\hbar}\left[\hat{\phi},\,\hat{H}'\right]=-\frac{i\lambda}{\hbar}\left[\hat{\phi},\,\hat{H}\right],
$$
$$
\frac{d\hat\Pi'}{dt}=\lambda\frac{d\hat\Pi}{dt}=-\frac{i}{\hbar}\left[\hat{\Pi}',\,\hat{H}'\right]=-\frac{i\lambda^2}{\hbar}\left[\hat{\Pi},\,\hat{H}\right],
$$
which are clearly inequivalent to the ones obtained before the rescaling.
Am I misunderstanding something, or is this really the case? And if so, is there any fundamental (physical) reason for the fact that the quantization procedure removes this invariance?

Commutator $[\phi,H] = \phi H - H\phi$ does not involve division by or differentiation by momentum, so it scales with $H$, and thus with $\lambda$.
This is in contrast to $\{\phi,H\}$, which involves differentiation of $H$ by momenta, and thus does not scale with $\lambda$.

is there any fundamental (physical) reason for the fact that the quantization procedure removes this invariance?

The fact Planck's constant $\hbar$ is non-zero. This also introduces a scale for angular momentum or energy steps, or size of atoms.

However, if you have a freedom in your classical action/Hamiltonian to fix an overall function $\mathcal{L}′=f(x)\mathcal{L}$, but this choice has an effect on the quantum theory, how do you pick the correct action to start with?

In classical theory the action and the Lagrangian have the scaling arbitrariness, they can be multiplied by any non-zero constant with no effect on equations of motion (well, if we want the action integral to obey the condition of having the minimum value for any infinitesimal motion element, and not merely the condition of having a stationary value, then the multiplying constant has to be positive, but other than that, it can have any value).
When we pass to an Hamiltonian formulation, this arbitrariness means  Hamiltonian and momenta are arbitrary in a similar way, having no effect on the motion, thus there is no single best Hamiltonian if the only thing we want is to get the correct equations of motion.
However, out of infinity of different valid Hamiltonian functions, there is the single special one $H_0$ that obeys the additional condition: that its value is the energy of the system (kinetic plus potential) as defined by the standard definition of energy for the system.
Thus e.g. for harmonic oscillator, $H_0 = \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{kx^2}{2}$ is the single special Hamiltonian whose value is energy of harmonic oscillator, and not e.g. $H = \frac{p^2}{32m} +16 \frac{kx^2}{2}$, because the latter, while being a fine Hamiltonian for the purposes of getting the equations of motion, gives 16 times greater energy than the correct value. Of course, the second Hamiltonian would give correct energy if $x$ in there referred to $1/4$ of the measured coordinate, but that is not how we usually use the symbol $x$.
When formulating quantum theory using an Hamiltonian operator using the canonical quantization recipe, this operator is sought from the set of as much similar functions of the cartesian quantities $x,p$ to the classical Hamiltonian function $H_0(p,x)$ giving energy, as possible. Thus we use the Hamiltonian function $H_0(p,x)$ to find the Hamiltonian operator candidates, and not just any Hamiltonian function possible. Then $\hbar$ to be used in the Schroedinger equation or the Heisenberg equations has the standard value. If we, for some reason, wanted to use rescaled Hamiltonian, e.g. one whose value is 16 times greater than energy, we would have to change the value of $\hbar$ to 1/16 of its standard value, to get the same time evolution. But there is usually no point doing this. The standard value we assign $\hbar$ refers to/is valid in the convention where differences of eigenvalues of the operator $H_0$ give changes of energy, and this is a useful convention.

@TopoLynch I've added an explanation to my answer.

Your final equations show that you just need a redefinition of $\hbar$ and scaling of $\hat \Pi$. It basically means that $\phi$ will have different amounts of quantum behavior, and the classical limit is reached faster, or slower.
This is much easier to see if we follow the opposite path: from QM to classical physics (thereby assuming that the former is the actual underlying theory). We then use the [path integral] to describe the time-evolution of the wave function, which contains the action in the exponent so it definitely will see $\lambda$ there, $\lambda/\hbar$ to be precise.
If we then use the stationary phase approximation to go to tha macroscopic limit, which means that only paths close to the one with "stationary action" will contribute, then it depends on $\lambda$ and on $\hbar$ where that approximation starts to  work. Introduction of $lambda$ is the same as redefining $\hbar$ (and then of course also the other things that depend on $\hbar$.)
This derivation of classical physics from QM, apart from being a validation of QM, also makes clear why "stationary action" is a rule to be used in the first place! It is just to identify the region without violently fluctuating phase in the path integral, which then becomes the only region that contributes.
So in summary: $\lambda$ has influence on the QM level and determines how fast you reach the classical limit, but once you have arrrived there it is no longer visible, as you described.

$\hbar$ introduces a scale with dimensions of action that means that a symmetry that rescales the action by an overall constant is no longer a symmetry in quantum theory. One way to see this is from the definition the path integral
$$
\int D x\ {\rm exp}\left(i\frac{S[x]}{\hbar}\right)
$$
The integrand would change if $S$ was rescaled by an overall constant (which could therefore affect various amplitudes).

Thank you! I have however one further question: typically you start from a classical action (or Hamiltonian) and then quantize it. As far as I understand, you pick an action such that the e.o.m.s. that it generates are the correct ones (Klein-Gordon, Dirac, and so on). However, if you have a freedom in your classical action/Hamiltonian to fix an overall function $\mathcal{L}'=f(x)\mathcal{L}$, but this choice has an effect on the quantum theory, how do you pick the correct action to start with?

@TopoLynch That's a good question :) There's actually a subtlety built in here, which is that you can rescale the fields and absorb the overall constant for a free theory. So if $S=Z \int d^4 x \left(-\frac{1}{2} (\partial \phi)^2 -\frac{1}{2}m^2 \phi^2\right)$, you can rescale $\phi\rightarrow \phi/\sqrt{Z}$ to absorb $Z$. The lack of ability to absorb $Z$ comes in when you start adding interactions, like if you added a $\lambda \phi^4$ term. Then, the usual prescription is to rescale the field to canonically normalize the action, so the kinetic term has the normalization (...)

(...) $-\frac{1}{2} (\partial \phi)^2$. This corresponds to a renormalization condition you might have seen in the LSZ formula that the pole in the propagator has a residue of $1$. Once you do this, then the scale of the interaction terms is fixed. Note that in QED, the fine structure constant $\alpha$ depends on $\hbar$; you can think of it as a coupling that's been fixed by this normalization procedure. It is a dimensionless quantity that represents the strength of the electromagnetic interactions.
